# variables not hoisting as expected in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hoisting

I've been following John Papa and his angular style guide recommendations.  I like the idea of putting all of your variables and methods available to the view up at the top of the controller and rely on javascript to hoist the variables at run time.  I clearly don't understand hoisting as well as I thought I did though.  In the following example I would expect the dumbValue variable declaration to be hoisted above the $scope.dumbValue assignment statement;

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', [$scope, $http]);
function MainCtrl($scope,$http)
{
    $scope.dumbValue = dumbValue;
    var dumbValue = 'dumb';
}
```

But in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iCC3j6QgGQfbwwJXZkdd?p=preview) you can see that that is not the case; The select ng-model value is not initialized.
If you move the assignment statement under the variable declaration, the ng-model is initialized.

Why doesn't javascript hoist the `var dumbValue` above the assignment, or is it and there's something about the way angular deals with it that I don't understand?

Comment: Hi, The variable gets hoisted as usual. But as in the rest of JavaScript the assignment doesn't hoist! That means, your `$scope.dumbValue` will get null/undifined assigned in this case.

Comment: If you think about, hoisting the assignment wouldn't make sense, since the RHS might depend on other values that have to be computed first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to link me to where Papa makes this recommendation for me to be sure, but I only see [Papa recommend doing this for "bindable members."](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controllers) He's talking about functions--not scalar values. You're trying to do the latter, and by doing so you run into a problem.

You see, hoisting moves *declaration* of variables to the top of a scope, but not their *definitions* (aka *assignments*). If you're declaring and defining in one statement, hoisting breaks it into two statements and hoists the former.

So this code:

```
var MainCtrl = function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.dumbValue = dumbValue;

    var dumbValue = 'dumb';
}
```

Is the same as writing this code (because hoisting turns it into this):

```
var MainCtrl = function ($scope,$http) {
    var dumbValue; // declared, not defined (hence the value `undefined`)

    $scope.dumbValue = dumbValue; // assignment of `undefined` to a property of $scope

    dumbValue = 'dumb'; // definition of your variable with a string value
}
```

As I said, however, Papa is talking about functions which will be bound to `$scope`. He says rather than do this:

```
var MainCtrl = function ($scope,$http) {
    function foo () {};

    $scope.foo = foo;
}
```

Do this:

```
var MainCtrl = function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.foo = foo;

    function foo () {};
}
```

This works because hoisting converts named function statements into variable declarations with definition of the new variable as a function, then splits them into two separate statements and puts them at the top. So Papa's recommended version (that last code block) is converted by hoisting to:

```
var MainCtrl = function ($scope,$http) {
    var foo;

    foo = function () {};

    $scope.foo = foo;
}
```

This different treatment of named function statements, as you can see, allows for `foo` to have been defined as a function before the binding to `$scope` takes place.

Personally, I don't like Papa's recommendation here. Although I personally understand hoisting and don't get bit by it, I have seen many developers create issues by writing code which gets changed in hoisting. This being the case, I am very particular to write my code exactly as the hoist would have converted it in order to avoid having my code misunderstood by the majority of developers. This is the way [JSLint's](http://www.jslint.com) default settings would have you write it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.  You were right - I was confused because I can rely on function statements to be hoisted the way I was using the variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this ...

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', [$scope, $http]);
function MainCtrl($scope,$http)
{
    $scope.dumbValue = dumbValue;
    var dumbValue = 'dumb';
}
```

this is actually what is happening.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', [$scope, $http]);
function MainCtrl($scope,$http)
{
    var dumbValue = undefined;
    $scope.dumbValue = dumbValue;
    dumbValue = 'dumb';
}
```

So the variable is hoisted, but is set to undefined. Then later it gets its value, but too late in this case. This is why hoisting of variables is not recommended. Always put those up top.